# Permission for URLs in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

May be this type of questions already exits but i didn't find proper solution. I am new in Laravel so sorry for this question.

I am creating a laravel application where user will login and will be access information .

My questions is how to prevent user to access direct URLs.

Comment: Any try. Can i see your code...

Comment: Please see this code added by me in router file for admin part

<?php 
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () { 
 Route::get('/admin/newjobs', 'JobsController@index');
 Route::post('/admin/newjobs', 'JobsController@create');
 
   
 Route::get('/admin/jobview/{id}','JobsController@jobview')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
  
 // job search for admin 
  Route::post('/admin/joblist', 'JobsController@listserach');
 /*Route::get('application', 'ApplicationController@index');*/
 Route::post('application', 'ApplicationController@insert_resume');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Rakesh's answer,

you can also apply the middleware to the controller for the routes you need protected via the constructor.

```
   public function __construct()
   {
        $this->middleware('auth');
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Put your routes under 'auth' middleware in routes.php file, that way only authenticated users will able to access.
for example like below:-

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', [
        'uses' => 'DashboardController@index',
        'as' => 'dashboard.index',
    ]);
});
```

Or you can write custom middleware for user validation.

Comment: Or you can write custom middleware for user validation.